# Is there any standard way to load parameters from a file in C++ on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux

Imaging that a program needs to know quite a lot of parameters to do its tasks properly, such as 'Port = 2323' this kind of things.

now I want to save these parameters in a plain text file, similar to Unix' system variables such as users and groups.

Is there any standard way/libraries that can help me to do this? Does anyone ever used them before? thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Boost.Program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/program_options.html) library. Is this you are looking for?

> The program_options library allows program developers to obtain program options, that is (name, value) pairs from the user, via conventional methods such as command line and config file.

Comment: You could also consider the brand-new (in 1.41) Boost.PropertyTree.  It supports reading INI files, if you like that syntax, and some other syntaxes (not to mention you can write your own parsers for it).

Comment: @John, that comment is worth its own answer.  Especially if you elaborate

Comment: I actually think Boost.ProgramOptions could be better than PropertyTree: it's more mature, and does support INI file processing (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1%5F41%5F0/doc/html/boost/program_options/parse_config_file.html).  I figured I'd toss PropertyTree in the mix just because it's a new thing in Boost which might also work, but I'm not comfortable recommending it over ProgramOptions.

Answer (score 1):

Qt offers this by default, and in a cross-platform way. Checkout out QSettings

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an alias or shell script that executes your program with given parameters. To conviniently get these parameters there's "getopt"

Answer (score 0):

[Link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/SimpleIni.aspx) here for a cross platform ini handler.

Hope this helps.